# Create multiple tables with CreateTable_management using rasters

Tags: python, arcpy

I am developing a script where I need to create multiple tables for rasters using arcpy.CreateTable_management. Here is the script and it does not work. What am I missing?

```py
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
import arcpy.da
import os

#read folder with raster data
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = path
targetFolder = arcpy.env.workspace
outFolder = r'\zonaldata.gdb'

#read raster data
rasterList = arcpy.ListRasters("*","All")
for i in rasterList:
    tab_template = r"\zonaldata.gdb\table_template"
    noTif = i.replace(".tif","")
    outName = os.path.join(outFolder, noTif + "_table")
    arcpy.CreateTable_management(outFolder, outName, tab_template)
```

Comment: Without the error, it's hard to tell exactly, but odds are the problem is here: `outName = os.path.join(outFolder, noTif + "_table")` which will end up something like `zonaldata.gdbRASTERNAME_table` -- catch the .gdb part? Doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several errors with the way you are building your path names, the first is you set the workspace to `path` but nowhere in your script do you define `path`?

Lets assume `path` is set to `r"C:\Temp"` and your zonaldata.gdb sits in that folder along with all the rasters you want to build tables for.

```
import arcpy,os
from arcpy.sa import *
import arcpy.da

# Initialise variables
path = r"C:\Temp"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = path
outGB = path + r'\zonaldata.gdb'
tab_template = r"\zonaldata.gdb\table_template"

#read raster data
rasterList = arcpy.ListRasters("*","All")
for i in rasterList:        
    noTif = i.replace(".tif","")
    outName = noTif + "_table"
    arcpy.CreateTable_management(outGB, outName, tab_template)
```

Your logic also ASSUMES that your raster names are valid table names so if your raster was 123xyz.tif then 123xyz_table would be an invalid table name for a file geodatabase. Explore using the function ValidateTableName() to ensure valid table names.

Comment: Thank you Hornbydd! This solved the issue.